# Writing Kusto.Explorer output to file on local computer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I wrote the following query to export data from [Kusto.Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer) to my local computer. However, the command below is not working. How can I do it?

```
.export to csv ("C:\\Downloads\\file.csv")
<| fullDay13_0to1_30
| project R, A
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason this should work, since you are using service-side export method.

###### [Export data to storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage)

> Executes a query and writes the first result set to an external
> storage, specified by a [storage connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage-connection-strings).
>
> Syntax
>
> .export [async] [compressed] to OutputDataFormat (
> StorageConnectionString [, ...] ) [with ( PropertyName = PropertyValue
> [, ...] )] <| Query

###### [Storage connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage-connection-strings)

> The following types of external storage are supported:
>
> - Azure Blob Storage
> - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
> - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1

You are looking for client-side export.

###### [Client-side export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/#client-side-export)

> In its simplest form, data export can be done on the client side. The client runs a query against the service, reads
> back the results, and then writes them. This form of data export
> depends on the client tool to do the export, usually to the local
> filesystem where the tool runs. Among tools that support this model
> are [Kusto.Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer) and [Web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-query-data).

There are other methods, including [Kusto CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-cli), [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/client-libraries), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/powershell/powershell) and [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/)

Comment: Kind reminder to check the answer